# Restlet basic HTTP Authentication : Help required

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I am running Restful web service on 8182 port using restlet framework. I am trying to authenticate user to hit the service. i.g.

I have a query string like this http://localhost:8182/api/service/customers/?key="XXXXXXXXX"

My doubts are:

1. How to get value of parameter key in Resource class/Application class, so i can authenticate user upon key through my custom database.
2. I don't have any client code for my restful service, since i want to invoke all call from browser itself. so please tell me,how  to send post data from browser itself. since i want to use post/put method to add new customer data.

I am using restlet framework 1.1.

Thanks in advance.

Karunjay Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bruno pointed out, you can obtain a `Form` instance to access the request's query parameters:

```
Form form = getRequest().getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm();
for (Parameter p : form) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + p.getName());
    System.out.println("Value: " + p.getValue());
}
```

If you want to use the `POST` method from the browser itself, I would recommend you use one of the following add-on/extensions:

[Firefox - REST Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/)

[Google Chrome - Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
getRequest().getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm()
```

This will return a [Form](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/api/org/restlet/data/Form.html) instance from which you can get the value of your query parameters (`getFirstValue("key")`, for example).

Comment: Thanks Bruno, for helping me, almost i loosed my confidence , but he helped me lot.